# How to sign request with Kentor SAML2 Token

Tags: c#, .net, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

If I want to call some API (rest service) after SAML2 authentication, how can I send signed request with SAML2 token to that IdP API server?

For example I'm signed in, but I want some additional data from IdP. I guess I need to provide SAML2 token.

Comment: Please describe more in detail what you want to do. Is there a REST service that requires a SAML2 Assertion as bearer token fro authentication? Or do you want to query the Idp for additional attributes, using a SAML2 protocol?

Comment: Behind the same IdP application which initiate SSO on my application is an REST API which I want to use to call some additional methods, and that API requires SAML2 assertion when I'm calling their methods.

But since you mentioned here, I would also like to know how can I query IdP for additional attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no build in support in AuthServices for forwarding the received SAML2 assertion in a REST call.

REST is usually handled by OAuth2/OpendID Connect instead of SAML2. But if you are ready to do some coding yourself you could set the SaveBootstrapContext flag to true in the identity configuration (in web.config if you use that, in SpOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration if you config in code). That will preserve the assertion on the generated identity. Then you can pick that upp and use it in your REST calls.

Comment: Ok, great! That would be fine I guess. Thanks for quick response.